# Identifiying Functional Dependencies

Tags: mysql, functional-dependencies

I am new to MySQL. I am making a small database and am having difficulty with functional dependencies. I would like to know how to identify the functional dependencies of my table.

Comment: dude, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functional dependency is written as `{X}` -> `{Y}`, where `X` and `Y` are both sets of attributes (one or more) from a table. The meaning is that for any pair of tuples, say `A` and `B`, in a `table`, if `A.X`(the values of `X` in `A`) is equal to `B.X`(the values of `X` in `B`), then `A.Y` is the same as `B.Y`.

Basically you need to know that every attribute in a table is functionally dependent on the key attributes. For other type of functional dependencies that are not determined by key attributes, you need to analyze whether a functional dependence is imposed or invalidated according your data.